# How to get position of node in html?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's assume, there is a main root node inside of which elements are placed.

```
<div class="root">
  <b>
    <i>text
      <span class="c">anotherpieceoftext
      </span>it still</b>continues
    </i>
</div>
```

By selection API I can get something like offset inside of one single node where the cursor begins and where does it end!

But I need to transform that data into a position of the character of HTML inside root element to wrap it in some text or do other editing capabilities.

Is there some finished solution for this? Is there a way around it without writing something like DOM?

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) what is exactly you are trying to achieve. Please provide a more detailed example of what you want to do. Also, what do you mean by "position"? Position within the DOM? Position on screen?

Comment: character of html...